# Cannot plot candlestick data in Gnuplot with a date/time field

Tags: datetime, gnuplot, candlestick-chart

To say this is frustrating is putting it mildly.  My sample data looks like so:

```
2012-04-30 20:00,1.32412,1.32412,1.32376,1.3239
2012-04-30 20:15,1.3239,1.32416,1.32378,1.32388
2012-04-30 20:30,1.32388,1.3241,1.32388,1.324
2012-04-30 20:45,1.324,1.32405,1.32385,1.32385
...
```

Where the fields are:

```
Date/Time,Open,High,Low,Close
```

My Gnuplot script for plotting this is simply:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%m/%d\n%H:%M"
set xrange ["2012-05-01 00:00":"2012-05-01 08:00"]
set yrange [*:*]
set grid
set key left
set datafile separator ","
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2:4:3:5 notitle with candlesticks
```

As you can see, I'm adjusting the column data to match the order that the candlesticks plot is expecting.  My data ranges from 2012-04-30 to 2012-05-31, so I'm only trying to plot 8 hours worth of data to start.  I have tried to set the xrange to `[*:*]`, but that only causes things to turn out worse.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was in the `timefmt` section.  Since I am using a 4-digit year, I needed to use `%Y` and not `%y`, i.e. case matters.  Hopefully this will clear things up for anyone else who is running into this strangeness.

Comment: Good catch :).  I'm glad you found your problem.